# Allow users to change Account owner (transfer record) but NOT edit Account Name?

Tags: field-level-security

We have a data model in which no changes can be made to fields on Accounts (Salesforce is not the system of record) but we would like users to be able to transfer ownership of accounts.
So far we have looked at the following ways of trying to do this:

- Set field to read-only on page layout (not possible for Account Name)
- Give user Read-access to Account object and Transfer Record permission (still not able to change owner)
- Validation rule that fires if anything *other* than Account Owner is changed (not able to write a validation rule for this)

Any other ideas??

Comment: Have you tried setting all field except owner Id and name as read only and then write a validation on ISCHANGED(NAME) for account?

Comment: did you consider a custom change owner button linked to a VF page?